# Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleObserver in modules in Android Studio app (Java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, duplicates, androidx

I searched for a long time on the Internet how to solve this error but did not find it.I tried to do a search as written [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#resolution_errors), but I did not find anything, maybe because I do not understand how to use it. What is this error? How to solve it? Help me pls.
P.S. Any necessary files or additional information I can add.

`Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleObserver found in modules lifecycle-common-2.4.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.4.0) and lifecycle-common-java8-2.3.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.3.0)`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    android {
        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4G"
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "31.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.###.###"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 20
        versionName "2.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'androidx.startup:startup-runtime:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:20.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.2'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.4.0'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.test:monitor:1.5.0'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.test.services:storage:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.github.florent37:expansionpanel:1.1.1'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.14.3'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lifecycle operates under a single version constraint - that means that every Lifecycle artifact you are using in your app should have the exact same version number (unfortunately, this is not something that Gradle will enforce for you).

Your error states that one of your dependencies is pulling in a dependency on `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.3.0`, which doesn't match the `2.4.0` version you are using of your other Lifecycle dependencies.

Therefore to fix your issue, add a dependency on the 2.4.0 version of `lifecycle-common-java8`:

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.4.0'
```